# Icecast - Too many open files

Tags: centos7, file-descriptor, icecast, ulimit

I'm running an Icecast 2.4.3 server on a CentOS 7. When I have a lot of listeners, I receive these errors and everything stops working:

```
[2017-06-21  18:56:37] WARN connection/_accept_connection accept() failed with error 24: Too many open files
```

It's running on "ices" user:

```
sudo -u ices /opt/icecast/bin/icecast -c /opt/icecast/etc/icecast.xml -b
```

Or running as root with "changeowner" option to "ices" user.

I set limits.conf:

```
ices         hard    nofile      65536
ices         soft    nofile      65536
```

From ulimit:

```
[root@orfeu inweb]# su ices
[ices@orfeu inweb]$ ulimit -n
65536
```

But when I check the PID, I get:

```
tcp        0      0 <IP>:8000       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21650/icecast

[root@orfeu inweb]# cat /proc/21650/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
...
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files
...
```

How can I fix this, to enforce 65536 file descriptors? Thank you.

Comment: The name is Icecast. No CamelCase. JFTR

Comment: It seems you built things from source and are struggling with starting things properly. I'd recommend to use the EPEL package of Icecast. It should come with a systemd service and there you can then also set the limits properly. It's up to date. (2.4.3 was a windows only release, 2.4.2 is latest on Unix/Linux)

Comment: I cant find icecast2 on CentOS7, even with EPEL installed. I did from source.

Comment: http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/7/x86_64/i/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I found a solution. Need to check when the problem happens again.

I realize that limits.conf set the limits *per user*.
I found out a way to set the limits *per process*.

```
/usr/bin/prlimit -n30000 -p `cat /var/run/icecast.pid`
```

Now I have:

```
Max open files            30000                30000                files
```

I don't know if there's a way to always start "icecast" binary with these limits, or always need to run the command against the PID after run.

Comment: I'd just use `ulimit` as part of the start script to set the desired value and then execute Icecast.